# Best way to change HTML text/elements when user is logged in?

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently working on a project for school which is getting/changing data through an API. On my site a user can log in and out. Basically I want, when the user is logged out a different text to appear than when the user is logged in.

I am working with Bootstrap and doing it this way at the moment:

```
<div class="row">
                <h1 class="<?php echo $successLogin ? "hidden" : "show"; ?>">Lorem Ipsum LOGGED OUT</h1>
                <h1 class="<?php echo $successLogin ? "show" : "hidden"; ?>">Welcome, <?php echo $user; ?></h1>
                <h3>Have a brief overview over your data!</h3>
</div>
```

Is this way okay? If not, how should I do it?

I hope you understand my question.

Have a nice day.

Comment: If $successLogin then show a h1 else show the other, don`t just hide them, my opinion.Try to use either $_SESSION or create an object with $_SESSION data You could wind up having a hidden form or such and witought proper validation ... you get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a class of hidden or show, you could just output the text.
Something like this would work.

```
<h1><?php echo $successLogin ? "Lorem Ipsum LOGGED OUT" : "Welcome, " . $user; ?></h1>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Much better now. Also thanks to KA_lin for showing me $_SESSION..... it's something I searched for a long time!